# Vue 3 updates even a toRaw object?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So i have this in the setup function of a component to do a backup in case someone cancels the editing:

```
const backupPoll = toRaw(props.poll);
```

in mounted() i do the following to get locally editable versions of the editable poll

```
this.title = this.poll.title;
this.question = this.poll.question;
this.timer = this.poll.timer;
this.options = this.poll.options;
```

this works for the most part, if i cancel everything resets except the options. these stay edited.

here's the html of the option and adding part:

```
<div class='option' v-for='(option, index) in options' :key='index'>
    <label class='option-label' :for='"option-" + index'>option {{ index + 1 }}</label>
    <base-button @click.prevent='removeOption(index)' v-if='index > 1' size='small' design='outline'>REMOVE</base-button>
    <input class='option-input' type="text" :name='"option-" + index' v-model='options[index]'>
</div>
<div class='button-bar'>
    <base-button @click.prevent='addOption'>+ OPTION</base-button>
    <div class='spacer'></div>
    <base-button @click.prevent='cancelPoll' class='button-right'>CANCEL</base-button>
    <base-button @click.prevent='savePoll' class='button-right' design='dark'>SAVE</base-button>
    <base-button @click.prevent='publishPoll' class='button-right' design='outline-dark'>PUBLISH</base-button>
</div>
```

and the functions used to update them:

```
removeOption(index) {
    this.options.splice(index, 1);
},
addOption() {
    console.log(this.backupOptions);
    this.options.push('');
    console.log(this.backupOptions);
},
```

upon canceling i call:

```
resetPoll() {
    const backupPoll = this.backupPoll;
    console.log(this.backupPoll);
    // this.$store.dispatch('polls/receivePollUpdate', this.backupPoll);
    this.title = backupPoll.title;
    this.question = backupPoll.question;
    this.timer = backupPoll.timer;
    this.options = backupPoll.options;
},
```

and this works for everything except the options array.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript objects and arrays are [copied by reference](https://javascript.info/object-copy).

`toRaw()` just returns the original object, so `backupPoll` points to the same object as the original. In `this.options = this.poll.options`, you're just copying a reference to the same array. Therefore, `backupPoll.options`, `this.options`, and `this.poll.options` are all the **same reference**.

One solution is to copy `this.poll.options[]` into a *new* array (using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#copy_an_array)):

```js
this.options = [...this.poll.options];
```